# PowerShell - Script works perfectly in the ISE, but not in the normal console

Tags: powershell

I am having an issue with the following script.
The script below has been written to detect any changes in directory $P1, and as soon as it detects these changes, it will be writing itself over directory $P2 (which is supposed to be an identical copy of $P1).

What is the issue you ask?
The script does work perfectly in the PowerShell ISE. As soon as it detects something it will update the $P2 folder.
However when being ran normally (As a local administrator) with powershell, it does nothing. I tought it was because the window instantly closed. However I adjusted this by making PowerShell always run in the -NoExit mode.
The Window does indeed now stay open, but still nothing happens when the updates to $P1 are being made. I am clueless about why it works in the ISE, but not in the basic PowerShell.

```
Function RunPrimaryScript {
# Update $P1 & $P2 to $P1 the actually Rdir and $P2 to the new location.

$DT = Get-Date
Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "[INFO] $DT - Script has started successfully."

## Set the paths.
$P1 = "C:\Tmp\TESTFILES\R-default"
$P2 = "C:\BHR\Rmap\"


## Check if the R-Folder excists, if not: end the script without closing.
if (!(Test-Path $P1)) {
$DT = Get-Date
Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "[ERROR] $DT - The R-directory cannot be found, the script has been stopped."
Break
}

## Checkif there's a copy already. Create it if there isn't.
if (!(Test-Path $P2)) {
Copy-Item -Path $P1 -Destination $P2 -Force -Recurse
$DT = Get-Date
Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "[WARNING] $DT - There was no copy of the R-directory. So it has been created."
}


## Index all subdirectories and files.
$GCP1 = Get-Childitem -Recurse -Path $P1
$GCP2 = Get-Childitem -Recurse -Path $P2


## Check for an excisting copy, if so: remove it.
if (Test-Path -Path "$P2") {
    $DT = Get-Date
    Remove-Item $P2 -Force -Recurse
    Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "[INFO] $DT - The R-directory copy on $P2 has been removed."
}
## Write new files.
Copy-Item -Path $P1 -Destination $P2 -Force -Recurse
## Log adjustements.
$DT = Get-Date
Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "[INFO] $DT - The following changes have been appended:"
Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $GCP2 -ReferenceObject $GCP1 -CaseSensitive | Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append
if (!(Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $GCP2 -ReferenceObject $GCP1 -CaseSensitive)) {
    $DT = Get-Date
    Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "[INFO] $DT - Files have had their content adjusted."
}
$DT = Get-Date
Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "[INFO] $DT - End of change list."
if ($Error) {
    $DT = Get-Date
    Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "[WARNING] $DT - While executing the script, the following error has been detected: $error"
}
$DT = Get-Date
Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "[INFO] $DT - The script has been successfully ended."
Out-File -FilePath C:\BHR\Rmap.log -Append -InputObject "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
}

## Live check for updates to the Rdir.
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Tmp\TESTFILES\R-default"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
RunPrimaryScript
}
$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action {
RunPrimaryScript
}
$deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action {
RunPrimaryScript
}
$renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action {
RunPrimaryScript
}
```

My script is partially based on [this script](http://dereknewton.com/2011/05/monitoring-file-system-changes-with-powershell/).

Comment: Seems like a permissions issue.  What does your invocation of the script look like when you run it from the console?

Comment: @rrirower When being ran from the Console (as local administrator, with everything running in local folders with no special permissions), nothing is being shown in the console. The script does not generate any output, it should write a log and copy the files. But it really does nothing in the console. While working 100% in the ISE.

Comment: Can you show the command you are using to start the script?  You mention -NoExit.  Are there any other command line args used?

Comment: @rrirower The script is simply being ran by starting it with PowerShell, it then AUTOMATICLY detects changes in the $P1 directory in order to run. There are no need for any args to run. I am simply running PowerShell in complete -NoExit mode.

Comment: Try using "Start-Transcript" to capture any output.  I would also try  using "-executionpolicy bypass" when you run the script.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's a scope problem.  Basically, the `FileSystemWatcher` doesnt know what `RunPrimaryScript` is because it's not defined when it goes to fire the trigger.  Something about the ISE keeps it in-scope.  Try replacing the function call with the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's a scope problem. Basically, the `FileSystemWatcher` doesnt know what `RunPrimaryScript` is because it's not defined when it goes to fire the trigger. Something about the ISE keeps it in-scope. Try replacing the function call with the body of the function.

[Copied from comments as this was the apparent solution.]

You might try specifying a scope when defining the function, or calling the function by referring to the scope.  See the [about_Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) page.